# Skip RSYNC files if Host is unreachable

Tags: rsync

I have an IP list that runs an rsync commands on a bunch of IP addresses.

However if a particular IP address in the file is offline, I get the following error code:

```
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) 
[sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.1]
```

Is there anyway to skip an IP if offline and carry on running against the rest of the IP's or set a timeout on trying and continue.

Answer (score 2):

Check it's available and run the `rsync` command only if successful. (This assumes that `ping` success equates to a remote login for `rsync`. Not guaranteed to be true in every situation but it can cover many of them.)

```
remote=192.168.1.1
ping -c1 -w3 -q "$remote" && rsync -avP src/ "$remote:dst"
```

The flags to `ping` tell it to wait for up to three seconds but continue as soon as it receives one response.

There are also timeout parameters for `rsync` (see the man page; search for `timeout`) but in my experience these can trigger on the transmission of a large file so I do not find them particularly useful.

Answer (score 0):

I came right with this.

My script had set -e in it, which sets it to exit if something fails.

So with Rsync failing to connect to a store, it stops the whole script, once I removed that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with Below script  and it worked fine

```
for i in `cat iplistfile`
do
ping -c2 $i >/dev/null
if [[ $? == 0 ]]
then
echo "$i is pinging"
ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' $i "exit"
if [[ $? == 0 ]]
then
echo "$i is sshable"
rsync command here
else
echo "$i is not sshable so no need to run rysnc command"
fi
else
echo "$i is not pinging"
fi
done
```